# Delphi - Desenhando a partir de coordenadas

Tags: delphi

Boa Noite,

Estou criando um programa para ler um arquivo .plt e deste arquivo retirar as coordenadas de X e Y e salvar em duas variaveis. Esta parte já consegui, agora preciso desenhar estas coordenadas no programa. Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei o Tcanvas porem não sei se é a melhor maneira para desenhar estas coordenadas. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: O que você quis dizer com "preciso desenhar estas coordenadas **no programa**"? você tem uma área da janela que quer desenhar, tem um paintbox ou algo assim?

Comment: Por que precisa "retirar as coordenadas de X e Y e salvar em **duas variaveis**". Não seria melhor usar o `TPoint`?